# How to reference functions with document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some functions in a JQuery document ready method that I would like to reference from other external files, but I keep getting a function undefined. How can I make those global?

ex.

```
external file 1

    $(function ()
    {
         function DoSomething()
         {    
            Do something
         }    
    });


external file 2

    $(function ()
    {

        Call DoSomething()
    )};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declare the functions outside the jQuery escope.

```
external file 1


         function DoSomething()
         {    
            Do something
         }    


external file 2

    $(function ()
    {

        Call DoSomething()
    )};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either define the function outside `.ready()` (as the other answers suggest), or you can take advantage of the fact that the `window` object *is* the global scope. So, you can make them global like this:

```
$(function(){
    function doSomething(){
        // …;
    }
    window.doSomething = doSomething;
});
```

Note that in this case they’ll only be defined *after* `.ready()` runs — if you want to use them immediately in another file (i.e. not inside an event handler or another `.ready()` function), this won’t work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to *define* functions outside ready blocks. That does not hurt. Only *executing* a function outside a ready block can cause issues if it uses the DOM before it's ready.

Defining does nothing (yet), and as such does not use the DOM. So it does not need to be inside a ready block; doing so only constrains the places where you can access it, which is basically only a disadvantage.

```
external file 1

function DoSomething()
     {    
        Do something
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible, declare functions outside of the ready check.

external file 1

```
function DoSomething()
{    
    Do something
}
```

external file 2

```
$(function ()
{
    Call DoSomething()
)};
```